# Adding a share point to a directory on Mac Server

Tags: macos

I want to be able to access my SVN repositories in /usr/local/repos as a share point ... When im in the mac File Sharing panel i cant see the /usr directory in the browse screen ... can i create a directory next to Applications etc etc called Repositories and link it to /usr/local/repos so that i can add it as a share point?

Can someone show me how i can do that?

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Best way would be to add `/usr/local/repos` to your `smb.conf` file manually.

Open up terminal, and type `sudo pico /private/etc/smb.conf`
Type in your password.

Inside the config file that opens, add a new section for the share you wish to add.

Example:

```
[Repositories]
    comment = Repositories
    path = /usr/local/repos
    guest ok = yes
    create mode = 0700
    writeable = yes
    browseable = yes
```

Save and exit the file with Control+O then Control+X.

Restart Windows File Sharing in System Preferences by turning it off and on.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using OS X Server, or just the file sharing capability built into the standard version of OS X?

If it's standard OS X and you're configuring share points in System Preferences -> Sharing -> File Sharing -> Shared Folders, selecting invisible folders is actually quite easy: click the + button to add a new folder, and then press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> and it'll show invisible files in the select dialog.

If you're using OS X Server, it's actually somewhat harder.  I don't know of any way to get Server Admin to show invisible items in its File Sharing section, but you can make the /usr folder visible with the command `sudo chflags nohidden /usr`, then configure sharing, then rehide it with `sudo chflags hidden /usr`.